# pygame button cannot run

Tags: python, loops, button, pygame

(English isn’t my first language, so please excuse any mistakes.)
(Thanks for everyone!!)

When I click the button"1", BE01 will appear but if I don't click, scene01Img will return.

I tried use gameExit = true in def BE01():, but it doesn't work.

```
pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac,(x,y,w,h))

        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()         
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic,(x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def BE01():
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    gameDisplay.blit(BE01Img,(0,0))
    button("BACK",350,450,100,50,black,gray,game_intro)

def game_intro():

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        gameDisplay.blit(introImg,(0,0))
        button("START",350,450,100,50,black,gray,game_loop)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)    

def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()   

def game_loop():
    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        gameDisplay.blit(scene01Img,(0,0))
        button("1",200,450,100,50,black,gray,BE01)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

game_intro()
game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

After click the button"1", BE01 will appear and run the another program, scene01 shouldn't appear.

Comment: `BE01` could assign `introImg` to `scene01Img` and then `game_loop` will display new image. But you have also new button in `BE01` so `BE01` should rather run new loop with new background and new button.

Comment: `gameExit` is local variable which exists only inside `game_loop` - to change it in `BE01` it has to be global variable. You can use `global gameExit` in every function in which you use varial `gameExit`

Comment: every scene should have own loop or every scene should have own function `draw` with `fill, blit, button` and replace this `draw` in `game_loop` when you press button. In Python you can assing function to variable ie. `show = print` and later use it `show("Hello World"). You can use global variable to keep function `draw` which you would run in `game_loop` and change `draw = draw_intro` or `draw = draw_game`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every scene should have own `loop` and when you press button then you should go to new `loop`.

If you want to change elements in one loop then put old elements in some function (ie. `draw_intro`) and new elements in other function (ie. `draw_other`) - at start uses `draw_intro` in loop and when you press button then replace this function with `draw_other`

In Python you can assign function name (without `()`) to variable

```
show = print
```

and later use this name (using `()`)

```
show("Hello World")
```

You can do the same with `draw_intro`, `draw_other`.

Inside game loop (before `while`)you can set

```
global draw

draw = draw_intro
```

and use it inside `while`

```
draw()
```

When you press button then it should replace funtion

```
draw = draw_other
```

---

Here full working code - I only removed all `blit(image)` to run it easily without images.

```
import pygame

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
gray  = (128,128,128)
red   = (255,0,0)

pygame.init()
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode( (800,600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac, (x,y,w,h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()         
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic, (x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",20)
    textSurf = smallText.render(msg, True, red)
    textRect = textSurf.get_rect()
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def change_draw(new_draw):
    global draw
    draw = new_draw

def draw_BE01():
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    #gameDisplay.blit(BE01Img,(0,0))
    button("BACK",350,450,100,50,black,gray,lambda:change_draw(draw_intro))

def draw_intro():
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    #gameDisplay.blit(introImg,(0,0))
    button("START",350,450,100,50,black,gray,lambda:change_draw(draw_other))

def draw_other():
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    #gameDisplay.blit(scene01Img,(0,0))
    button("1",200,450,100,50,black,gray,lambda:change_draw(draw_BE01))

def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()   

def game_loop():
    global draw

    draw = draw_intro

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        draw()

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you didn't use `lamda` before then you can do it without `lambda` but you will need `change_draw_to_intro`, `change_draw_to_other`, `change_draw_to_BE01` instead of single `change_draw`

```
import pygame

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
gray  = (128,128,128)
red   = (255,0,0)

pygame.init()
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode( (800,600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac, (x,y,w,h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()         
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic, (x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",20)
    textSurf = smallText.render(msg, True, red)
    textRect = textSurf.get_rect()
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def change_draw_to_intro():
    global draw
    draw = draw_intro

def change_draw_to_other():
    global draw
    draw = draw_other

def change_draw_to_BE01():
    global draw
    draw = draw_BE01

def draw_BE01():
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    #gameDisplay.blit(BE01Img,(0,0))
    button("BACK",350,450,100,50,black,gray,change_draw_to_intro)

def draw_intro():
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    #gameDisplay.blit(introImg,(0,0))
    button("START",350,450,100,50,black,gray,change_draw_to_other)

def draw_other():
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    #gameDisplay.blit(scene01Img,(0,0))
    button("1",200,450,100,50,black,gray,change_draw_to_BE01)

def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()   

def game_loop():
    global draw

    draw = draw_intro

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        draw()

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```